# Regex help grabbing values from urls

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling with creating a regular expression to print the part of the url that I want.  With PHP I am grabbing the path after the primary domain name.  They look something like :

```
this-link-1
this-is-another-one-3
```

The php I am using to grab these is like :

```
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$whereami =  parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
echo $whereami;
```

Can someone help me write a regular expression to always remove the -# for the whereami variable ?  So from this example $whereami would be `this-link` and `this-is-another-one` after run through the expression

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_replace("/-\d+$/", "", $whereami)
```

Example:

```
echo preg_replace("/-\d+$/", "", "this-is-another-one-3");
```

Output:

```
this-is-another-one
```

Comment: Yes! This works great, with how helpful SO is I am never going to learn regex :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it without regex:

```
echo implode('-', explode('-', 'this-link-1', -1));
```

Result:

```
this-link
```